# Flask-login raising 401 status on pages with @login_required

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

The issue I am having is that after logging into my application I am sometimes getting a 401 unauthorized status on pages with @login_required. If I refresh the page it works (sometimes I need to refresh multiple times before being given access). Happy to get any feedback as to why the app is behaving this way because I haven't succeeded in figuring out where my mistake is. I appreciate any advice on where to look (and additional feedback that comes up).

I have a user_loader function in the models.py file (not part of the user class)

```
@login_mgr.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)
```

And here is the route for the login page:

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = forms.Login()
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if User.authenticate(email, password):
            login_user(user, remember=True)       
            return flask.redirect('/user-info')
        else:
            return flask.redirect('login')
    return flask.render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Authenticate function in User class:

```
@classmethod
def authenticate(cls, email, password):
        user = cls.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            if user.password == password:
                return True
            else:
                flask.flash('Email or password incorrect', category='danger')
                return False
        else:
            flask.flash('No account associated with that email. Please sign up', category='danger')
            return False
```

Comment: @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):

Comment: Hi @LinhNguyễnNgọc I had a feeling that my issue is somewhere in the user loader, could you explain what exactly the problem is? (login_mgr is declared in my init file so:

login_mgr = flask_login.LoginManager()

Comment: lastime i have the same problem, i change to: @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first(), and it run well, wait, i will post full code of my app

Answer (score -1):

I dont know exactly problems for you, but i post my code, i hope it is usefull for you.
**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
import dir
from flask_mail import Mail
import flask_excel as excel
# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy()
mail = Mail()


firebase_path = str(dir.dir) + '/project/firebase/FirebaseAdminSDK.json'

GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID = "880298757050-xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxx"
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = False
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key-goes-here'

    # app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////' + str(dir.dir) + '/admin.sqlite'
    app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
    app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
    app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'xxxxxxxx'
    app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
    app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
    app.config['OAUTH_CREDENTIALS']  = {
        'google': {
            'id': GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID,
            'secret': GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET
        }
    }
    excel.init_excel(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    from .models import User
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()



    # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    from .serv import serv as serv_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(serv_blueprint)

    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from .search import search as sear_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(sear_blueprint)

    from .dash import dash as dash_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(dash_blueprint)

    from .dlf import dlf as dlf_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(dlf_blueprint)

    from .contact import contact as contact_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(contact_blueprint)


    from .appexcel import appexcel as appexcel_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(appexcel_blueprint)

    from .appreport import appreport as appreport_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(appreport_blueprint)


    return app
```

The models

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
now = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=7)
now = datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour,now.minute,now.second)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(30))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(30))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(10))
    password = db.Column(db.String(20))
    brands = db.Column(db.String(20))
    carclass = db.Column(db.String(20))
    biensoxe = db.Column(db.String(8))
    favourite_shop = db.Column(db.String(30))
    address = db.Column(db.String(50))
    provinces = db.Column(db.String(20))
    token = db.Column(db.String(8))
    shop_token = db.Column(db.String)
    created_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    avatar = db.Column(db.String)
```

auth.py

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    if current_user is not None and current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('login.html')

@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    if not password:
        flash('Vui lòng điền mật khẩu')
        return redirect(request.referrer)
    else:
        remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        # check if the user actually exists
        # take the user-supplied password, hash it, and compare it to the hashed password in the database
        if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            flash('Kiểm tra lại thông tin hoặc sử dụng google login để đăng nhập nhanh chóng')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))  # if the user doesn't exist or password is wrong, reload the page

        # if the above check passes, then we know the user has the right credentials
        login_user(user, remember=remember)
        try:
            user_shop_token = current_user.shop_token
            if Shop.query.filter_by(shop_token = user_shop_token).first():
                return redirect(url_for('dash.manage'))
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))
```

I use flask-login, and use blueprint
I learn how to use [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login)

Comment: Thanks! I am also using blueprint. I realized that when the app is in the development environment (using SQLite) it works and calls the user_loader function when appropriate (and gets the appropriate response). When I switch to production (Postgres) something is going wrong with the user_loader function. 

I tried changing my function to use "query.filter_by" as you did but the problem persists. Thanks for your tip, it gave me some more things to check out. I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: Maby you change to slq,not sqlite,i use sqlite and some time i have problems, because slqite not support two query one time.

Comment: So, I am using postgres in production (sqlite is adequate for development). What is interesting I just checked is in production the user_loader function isn't being called every time a new page with @login_required loads. So I guess I need to sort that out

Comment: Further update (still having issues) further research seemed to show that the issue might be that chrome sometime doesn't accept cookies in various situations. This is not the case (cookies are passed in both the allowed request and the blocked request). 

I checked the logs in heroku, and it seems that for whatever reason the load_user function just isn't always called. The logs are below. I did try removing the remember=True from the login() function, it seems to have made the problem more prevalent. Below are the logs.

Comment: 401: 
2020-10-01T22:00:31.529046+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.87.172 - - [01/Oct/2020:22:00:31 +0000] "GET /user-info HTTP/1.1" 401 338 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
2020-10-01T22:00:31.529133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/user-info" host=apptrak20.herokuapp.com request_id=78a3385c-c7f5-4940-a3ba-972d49de2e9c fwd="109.65.32.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=401 bytes=509 protocol=https

Comment: 200: 
2020-10-01T22:00:35.920348+00:00 app[web.1]: load user called
2020-10-01T22:00:35.932474+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.87.172 - - [01/Oct/2020:22:00:35 +0000] "GET /user-info HTTP/1.1" 200 3661 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
2020-10-01T22:00:35.939065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/user-info" host=apptrak20.herokuapp.com request_id=e6d16dc3-e920-43f3-bfb9-418c6fdf9cf4 fwd="109.65.32.216" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=3837 protocol=https